# Max Area Bounded by $y^2=4ax$, $y=ax$ and $y=\frac x a$

Tags: calculus, integration

I have the following problem which I got from an maths Instagram account that I want to solve:

https://www.instagram.com/p/CTMxl-gpfXo/?utm_source=ig_web_copy_link

> Find the maximum area bounded by the curves $y^2=4ax$, $y=ax$ and $y=\frac x a$ such that $a\in [1,2]$

I have plotted the functions into the graphing calculator desmos and I have the following graph where a=1.5.

[image]

My question is what area are they referring to? The area bounded by three curves seems somewhat odd question considering you have two linear functions. Ignoring the purple function $y=\frac x a$

$$A= \int_0^{k}\sqrt{4ax}-ax dx$$
$k$ is the intersection of $y=ax$ and $y^2=4ax$ Therefore $x(a^2 x-4a)=0\Rightarrow k=4/a$
$$\Rightarrow A= \int_0^{4/a}\sqrt{4ax}-ax dx= \Big[\frac 4 3 \sqrt{(ax)^3} -\frac a 2 x^2 \Big]^{4/a}_0= \frac {32} {3a}- \frac 8 a =\frac{8}{3a} $$

It seems like a really strange problem but I want to clarify if I have done it correctly. Thank you for your time. Perhaps I should stay away from Instagram if I want to learn maths

Comment: It seems to be the area enclosed by the green line (left), the purple area (bottom) and red parabola (right). I guess the result is not depending from the variable $a$ anymore. The same question including a solution is given here https://www.toppr.com/ask/question/the-maximum-area-bounded-by-the-curves-y2-4axy-axa-and-y/

Comment: I have the same integral like at the answer of José Santos. But I don´t think that it can be solved algebraically.

Comment: When I integrate the result of José Carlos Santos, I get $\frac{8 \left(-3 a^8+4 \left(\left(a^4\right)^{3/2}-1\right) a^2+3\right)}{3 a^3}$. Unfortunatelly it differs from the second solution given by Math Lover.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Interestingly in mathematics, straight line is also a curve ([wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curve))

So coming to the question, it is the area that are bound by $3$ curves, two of which are straight lines. So it should be the area that is shaded in the below diagram.

[image]

Intuitively, the bound area should increase as the difference in slopes of both straight lines increases - one of them has slope $a$ and the other has slope $\displaystyle\frac{1}{a}$.

The difference in slope is max at $a = 2$. This is also given that the aperture of parabola $y^2 = 4ax$ increases as $a$ increases.

You found the area bound between $y^2 = 4ax$ and $y = ax$, which is $ \displaystyle \frac{8}{3a}$. This area $ \displaystyle \frac{8}{3a}$ reduces as $a$ increases for $a \geq 1$.

Similarly the area bound between $y^2 = 4ax$ and $x = ay$ is,

$\displaystyle \int_0^{4a^2} \int_{y^2/4a}^{ay} dx ~ dy = \frac{8a^5}{3} ~$. This area will increase as $a$ increases (given $a \geq 1$).

So the area bound by all three curves is max at $a = 2$ and is given by -

$\displaystyle \frac{8}{3} \left(a^5 - \frac{1}{a} \right)$.

Answer (score 0):

The region bounded by the three lines is the region above the parabola and below both straight lines. The parabola and the purple straight line meet at $\left(4a^3,4a^2\right)$ (besides $(0,0)$, of course) and the parabola and the green straight line meet at $\left(\frac4a,4\right)$ (again, besides $(0,0)$). Since $a\geqslant1$, $\frac4a\leqslant4a^3$. So, the area is equal to$$\int_0^{4/a}ax-\frac xa\,\mathrm dx+\int_{4/a}^{4a^3}\sqrt{4ax}-\frac xa\,\mathrm dx.$$